# Installed gems not found in $GEM_HOME/bin

Tags: ruby, path, rubygems

I installed

```
$ gem install jekyll-feed jekyll-seo-tag
```

for my user but they do not appear in $GEM_HOME/bin:

```
$ ls $GEM_HOME/bin
bundle  bundler  jekyll
```

What could go wrong?

Comment: are you using a ruby management system like `rvm` or `rbenv`? do you have a `.ruby-gemset` file in the root of your project?

Comment: No I do not use them. Which one do you recommend?

Comment: I've been using https://rvm.io/ for years.  MacOS people seem to favour rbenv https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv ... rbenv is "lighter", but if you ahve to work with multiple versions of Ruby, rvm works better (IMHO)

Comment: `$GEM_HOME/bin` directory only contains the executables the actual gems are inside `$GEM_HOME/gems` folder.